# Failing to store captured image in external storage

Tags: java, android

I am trying to store a captured image to my storage but getting the errors:

- E/GREC: /storage/emulated/0/screenshotdemo.jpg (Permission denied)
- java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/screenshotdemo.jpg (Permission denied)

My code is below:
MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ScrollView scrollView;
private Button btn;
public static Bitmap bitScroll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.takeScreenshot);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bitScroll = getBitmapFromView(scrollView, scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());
            saveBitmap(bitScroll);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

//create bitmap from the ScrollView
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "screenshotdemo.jpg";
    File imagePath = new File(mPath);


    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imagePath.getAbsolutePath() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For Android 10 devices you should request legacy external storage in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

You dont have the permissions to access the storage
here is a link to the dev guide
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: Hi, I have this added into the Manifest and still experiencing this problem.

Comment: if you are targeting android 10 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Comment: so in android 10 you will have to request permissions at runtime

Comment: if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,Manifest.permission.INETRNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Internet permission granted
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Permission granted.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    // Internet permission not granted
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Permission not granted.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

Comment: It says permission granted but still getting the same error message

Comment: you have to put your code for images in the if else statement

Comment: I did and it says permission granted but doesn't save.

Comment: i am now getting this error:2020-11-25 11:48:52.679 1612-1685/? E/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl: getInputForAttr permission denied: recording not allowed for uid 10038 pid 24918

Comment: You need permissions for audio, unsure what it is but a quick google ssearch would help you out